# How to fix error 400 error when creating event using Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling, google-api

when trying to create an event using computed variables, i keep getting bad request error and i'm not sure why. i have no problems creating events with hardcoded values, here's my code on how to create an event using both hardcoded values and computed as described by eventObj and eventObjC:

```
 const eventObj = {
        end: {
          dateTime: "2022-11-16T22:15:00-08:00",
          timeZone: "America/Vancouver",
        },
        start: {
          dateTime: "2022-11-16T22:00:00-08:00",
          timeZone: "America/Vancouver",
        },
        summary: "sample event",
        description: "sample event description",
      };

      var date = {
        value: "2022-11-16",
      };
      var startTime = {
        value: "02:30",
      };
      var endTime = {
        value: "03:00",
      };
      var d = DateTime.fromISO(dt.toISOString(), { zone: timezone });
      var GMTOffset = d.toFormat("ZZ");
      var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
      
      var eventObjC = {
        end: {
          dateTime: date.value + "T" + startTime.value + ":00" + GMTOffset,
          timeZone: timezone,
        },
        start: {
          dateTime: date.value + "T" + endTime.value + ":00" + GMTOffset,
          timeZone: timezone,
        },
        summary: "sample event",
        description: "sample event description",
      };

      var options = {
        method: "POST",
        async: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(eventObjC),
      };

      async function createEvent() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fetch(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" +
              calendarId +
              "/events",
            options
          )
            .then((response) => response.json()) // Transform the data into json
            .then(function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              resolve(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        });
      }
      console.log(eventObj);
      console.log(eventObjC);
      var tester = createEvent();
```

i've also tried printing out eventObj and eventObj as you can all see, and here are the  results, they look identical:
[image]

ahh, @Jaromanda X has said, i now see the correct error, it's stating an empty time range for some reason. console.log(eventObjC) states otherwise though:

[image]

Comment: you mention a 400 error ... any further info - have you checked the API documentation to make sure you are sending correctly formed request?

Comment: Wild Guess. By any chance you are using past date ?

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply @JaromandaX! yes the documentation has helped me create an event in the first place, as per eventObj, however i am having a problem creating an event using eventObjC. judging from the screenshot, they both look identical in structure so i'm not sure why i'm getting a 400 error.

Comment: sorry @SubirKumarSao what did you mean past date? if you meant the date variable, i have jus changed it to 2022-11-17 (the next day for me) but i still encounter the error

Answer (score 0):

if you all take a look, the error occurs because i set my end to be startTime and start to be endTime, thus getting an error. thank you to Jaromanda X and Subir for pointing me in the right direction, checking full error logs and checking the data you're pushing into requests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).